# Taking experimental errors into account in lmfit

Tags: python-3.x, curve-fitting, lmfit

I am trying to implement `lmfit` into my fitting routines, and I am having issues defining the errors. I premise that I read previous questions regarding the topic on this platform, and I also went through the docs, but some of my doubts are still there.

Below is a complete and minimal example of what I am trying to achieve.

```
import corner
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import lmfit


font = {'fontname':'candara', "fontweight":"light"}
plt.style.use('ggplot')
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (8,4)
ax_fit_kws = dict(xlim=(0,0.12), ylim=(0.5,1.1))
ax_res_kws = dict(xlim=(0,0.12), ylim=(-0.1,0.1))

def mono_exp(SL_array, a, b):
    model = a * np.exp(-b * SL_array)
    return model
model = lmfit.Model(mono_exp)

SL_array = np.array((0.030, 0.040, 0.060, 0.080, 0.10))
data= np.array((1., 0.9524336, 0.92452666, 0.87995659, 0.82845576))
errs = np.array((0.00029904, 0.00049384, 0.00076344, 0.00053886, 0.00066012))

params = model.make_params(a=0, b=0)

result = model.fit(data=data, params=params, SL_array=SL_array, method="Nelder", markersize=10, weights=errs)

lmfit.report_fit(result)
result.plot(yerr = errs, ax_fit_kws=ax_fit_kws, ax_res_kws=ax_res_kws)

emcee_kws = dict(steps=400, burn=30, thin=20, is_weighted=False,
                 progress=True)
emcee_params = result.params.copy()
emcee_params.add('__lnsigma', value=np.log(0.1), min=np.log(0.001), max=np.log(2.0))
result_emcee = model.fit(data=data, SL_array=SL_array, params=emcee_params, method='emcee',
                         nan_policy='omit', fit_kws=emcee_kws)

lmfit.report_fit(result_emcee)

ax = plt.plot(SL_array, model.eval(params=result.params, SL_array=SL_array), label='Nelder', zorder=100)
result_emcee.plot_fit(ax=ax, data_kws=dict(color='gray', markersize=10), yerr = errs)
emcee_corner = corner.corner(result_emcee.flatchain, labels=result_emcee.var_names,
                             truths=list(result_emcee.params.valuesdict().values()))
plt.show()
```

My problem is rather simple: I would like the initial `Nelder` fitting routine to take into account the `errs` array as errors on the `data` array (which are my experimentally determined points). I am not sure that calling `weights=errs` achieves this goal. I have tried the solution implemented here: [How do I include errors for my data in the lmfit least squares miniimization, and what is this error for conf_interval2d function in lmfit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15255928/how-do-i-include-errors-for-my-data-in-the-lmfit-least-squares-miniimization-an/15979525)
But I could not make it work.

Another point which is not really clear to me is: does the `emcee` part of my fit take into account the residuals from the `Nelder` routine?

Many thanks in advance!

EDIT

After a bit more of research, I now believe that when calling weights I should actually give `1/err`. By implementing this change, and applying `scale_covar=False` as described elsewhere ([How to properly get the errors in lmfit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59296990/how-to-properly-get-the-errors-in-lmfit?rq=1)) while artifically incrementing the error values (for instance, deliberate multiplication of the `errs` array by 100-fold) I do get the fitted parameters errors to increase substantially, which is an expected behaviour. In short: `result = model.fit(data=data, params=params, SL_array=SL_array, method="Nelder", markersize=10, weights=errs)` was changed to `result = model.fit(data=data, params=params, SL_array=SL_array, method="Nelder", markersize=10, weights=1/errs)`. Is this correct?

I am still rather confused on the implementation of `emcee` in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you say in your edits is correct:   You want to use `weights=1./err` to properly weight the residual of `data` and `model` by the uncertainties in the data, `err`.

You probably want to use the same in your call to `model.fit(..., method='emcee')` too.

I should say that the use of `emcee` in `lmfit` is rather confusing and gives the unfortunate impression that it is doing a fit. This is simply not true, as `emcee` (and, really MCMC as a method) can not really do a fit in the sense of "systematically refine parameter values in order to find an improved solution".  What it is doing is exploring parameter space in the vicinity of the input parameter values (that happen to be the solution from the `Nelder` method).
This exploration may find (more like "stumble upon" than "seek") an improved solution and the results will reflect the exploration it does.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. What I am trying to achieve is actually using the array containing the residuals in the Nelder fit, and use those as errors in emcee. Could you suggest me how to achieve this goal? When I print the array `result.residual` at the end of the code above (i.e., in my intentions the residuals coming from the Nelder fit) I actually get absurdly large numbers (4 or 5 orders of magnitude larger than the actual ones displayed in the plot resulting from `result.plot(yerr = errs, ax_fit_kws=ax_fit_kws, ax_res_kws=ax_res_kws)`